# MySQL subtotal based on duplicate

Tags: mysql

So I have the following tables in MySQL:

```
Table1:
Col1  Team
100   A
100   B
100   C
200   D
200   A
200   C
300   A

Table2:
Team  Col2
A     1
B     2
C     3
D     4
```

What I would like to do is get a sum of Table2.Col2 for and grouped by Team where there are dups in Table1.Col1 (more than one occurrences).  The desired output should be:

```
Col1  Col2
100   3     ( 1 + 2 + 3 )
200   8     ( 1 + 3 + 4 )
```

Value of 300 for Col1 should not be outputted since there is only one instance of it in Table1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select t1.col1, sum(t2.col2)
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.team = t2.team
group by t1.col1
having count(t1.team) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right then answer is

```
select table1.Col1, Sum(table2.Col2) from table1 
left join table2 on table1.Team = table2.Team group by Col1 
having count(table1.Col1) > 1
```